# Free monad and the free operation

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory, free-monad

One way to describe the Free monad is to say it is an *initial* monoid in the category of endofunctors (of some category `C`) whose objects are the endofunctors from `C` to `C`, arrows are the natural transformations between them. If we take `C` to be `Hask`, the endofunctor are what is called `Functor` in haskell, which are functor from `* -> *` where `*` represents the objects of `Hask`

By initiality, any map from an endofunctor `t` to a monoid `m` in `End(Hask)` induces a map from `Free t` to `m`.

Said otherwise, any natural transformation from a Functor `t` to a Monad `m` induces a natural transformation from `Free t` to `m`

I would have expected to be able to write a function

```
free :: (Functor t, Monad m) => (∀ a. t a → m a) → (∀ a. Free t a → m a)
free f (Pure  a) = return a
free f (Free (tfta :: t (Free t a))) =
    f (fmap (free f) tfta)
```

but this fails to unify, whereas the following works

```
free :: (Functor t, Monad m) => (t (m a) → m a) → (Free t a → m a)
free f (Pure  a) = return a
free f (Free (tfta :: t (Free t a))) =
    f (fmap (free f) tfta)
```

or its generalization with signature

```
free :: (Functor t, Monad m) => (∀ a. t a → a) → (∀ a. Free t a → m a)
```

Did I make a mistake in the category theory, or in the translation to Haskell ?

I'd be interested to hear about some wisdom here..

PS : code with that enabled

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}
import Control.Monad.Free
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Haskell translation seems wrong. A big hint is that your `free` implementation doesn't use monadic bind (or join) anywhere. You can find `free` as [`foldFree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12/docs/src/Control-Monad-Free.html#foldFree) with the following definition:

```
free :: Monad m => (forall x. t x -> m x) -> (forall a. Free t a -> m a)
free f (Pure a)  = return a
free f (Free fs) = f fs >>= free f
```

The key point is that `f` specializes to `t (Free t a) -> m (Free t a)`, thus eliminating one `Free` layer in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the category theory part, but the Haskell part is definitely not well-typed with your original implementation and original type signature.

Given

```
free :: (Functor t, Monad m) => (∀ a. t a → m a) → (∀ a. Free t a → m a)
```

when you pattern match on `Free tfta`, you get

```
tfta :: t (Free t a)
f :: forall a. t a -> m a 
free :: (forall a. t a -> m a) -> forall a. Free t a -> m a
```

And thus

```
free f :: forall a. Free t a -> m a
```

leading to

```
fmap (free f) :: forall a. t (Free t a) -> t (m a)
```

So to be able to collapse that `t (m a)` into your desired `m a`, you need to apply `f` on it (to "turn the `t` into an `m`") and then exploit the fact that `m` is a Monad:

```
f . fmap (free f) :: forall a. t (Free t a) -> m (m a)
join . f . fmap (free f) :: forall a. t (Free t a) -> m a
```

which means you can fix your original definition by changing the second branch of `free`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}

import Control.Monad.Free
import Control.Monad

free :: (Functor t, Monad m) => (∀ a. t a → m a) → (∀ a. Free t a → m a)
free f (Pure  a) = return a
free f (Free tfta) = join . f . fmap (free f) $ tfta
```

This typechecks, and is probably maybe could be what you want :)

Comment: indeed, and it's a nice alternative to the other answer using join instead of bind. I wish I could mark those two answers as correct

Comment: Note that this `free` is in terms of the recursion principle for `Free`: `free f = fold (join . f) return` where `fold :: Functor f => (f b -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Free f a -> b`. In comparison, the library [`foldFree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12/docs/src/Control-Monad-Free.html#foldFree) with `>>=` doesn't require a `Functor` constraint, because the `Free` data type in Haskell is valid for all `f :: * -> *` parameters, and we can compute on that structure directly (although `Free f a` with non-functor `f` isn't very useful).